# AC portable / sink

Tags: plumbing, sink, portable-ac

So I recently installed a portable/ room ac (Toshiba) with the whole window set up etc. it is only connected to the wall for with the plug and the vent out the window. Would this cause my sinks to smell? I noticed that my kitchen and bathroom are starting to smell super bad like spoiled dirt but noticed the smell is acting up when the ac is on. I live in a 500ft studio if that is important. It seems like a dumb question but this can’t be a coincidence that every time the ac is on, there is a horrendous smell. However it is not always present when the ac is on but for the vast majority it is and it’s bothering me so much. Also the ac unit itself is brand new and does not smell at all when I’m inspecting it on or off. I also checked the vents and there wasn’t anything concerning.  Any help would be appreciated. I have someone coming to look at it but I’d like to see what you guys think

Comment: If you take a bunch of air out of a room, replacement air has to come from somewhere.  It's going to come in through any/every leak in your house.  This "make-up" air is a) HOT, b) WET meaning the A/C must sacrifice some of its capacity to dehumidify it, and c) SMOKY/STINKY/whatever is going on outside that you don't want to just open your windows and let the breeze cool you.   Portables with only 1 hose aren't very good, because of that. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-mBeYC2KGc

Answer (score 3):

Your portable air conditioner is pulling air through the unit, but also exhausting air to the outside via the window vent. The air that is being exhausted must have a source.

If your room is even reasonably sealed, the air may be getting pulled from your plumbing system's venting. In non-air-conditioning circumstances, the foul odors would be exiting through the vents, but the AC is creating a low pressure area in the room and the air from the vent is providing some of the volume needed.

Provide a different source to compensate for the volume of air being forced through the window vent and you may reduce or eliminate the odor from the plumbing.